# truecrypt 1: Syntax error: “(” unexpected

Tags: executable, arm, truecrypt

I want to use truecrypt on a Linux machine. It is CLI mode only. So I downloaded the x64 and x86 and tried or run the extracted executable file for each version (x64 & x86), but it doesn't work. It gives me:

```
./truecrypt

./truecrypt: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I'm running MontaVista Linux Professional Edition 4.0 (0501140) `Linux/armv5tejl 2.6.10_mvl401-davinci_102_mw`.

It's 2.6.10 kernel. Truecrypt supports 2.6 kernels.

So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your processor is `armv5tejl`.  Neither `x86` nor `x64` binaries can run on it.  You need an ARM version of your binary.